# Compatible Ruby and Cocoapods versions

Tags: ruby, flutter, macos, cocoapods

I am developing a Flutter app for Android and iOS. The app is in a stable state of development on the Android simulator so I thought I would try to run it on the iOS simulator. The Flutter installation process on Macos requires installing Cocoapods. After trying to use the Macos installation of Ruby and encountering permission errors, I decided to try asdf, the latest version of Ruby (Ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [x86_64-darwin21]), and Cocoapods (1.11.2). The installation appeared to be successful, but running pod results in the following error:

Error loading the plugin `cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0`.

NoMethodError - undefined method `activate' for #<Gem::StubSpecification:0x00007f963819f4f8 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @loaded_from="/Users/kevin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gemspec", @data=#<Gem::StubSpecification::StubLine:0x00007f9638194850 @name="cocoapods-plugins", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.0.0">, @platform="ruby", @extensions=[], @full_name="cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0", @require_paths=["lib"]>, @name=nil, @spec=#<Gem::Specification:0x00007f96381cc278 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kevin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @bin_dir=nil, @cache_dir=nil, @cache_file=nil, @doc_dir=nil, @ri_dir=nil, @spec_dir=nil, @spec_file=nil, @gems_dir="/Users/kevin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @base_dir="/Users/kevin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @loaded=true, @activated=true, @loaded_from="/Users/kevin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gemspec", @original_platform=nil, @installed_by_version=#<Gem::Version "3.3.2">, @autorequire=nil, @date=2016-05-10 00:00:00 UTC, @description="                         This CocoaPods plugin shows information about all available CocoaPods plugins\n                         (yes, this is very meta!).\n                         This CP plugin adds the \"pod plugins\" command to CocoaPods so that you can list\n                         all plugins (registered in the reference JSON hosted at CocoaPods/cocoapods-plugins)\n", @email=nil, @homepage="https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods-plugins", @name="cocoapods-plugins", @post_install_message=nil, @signing_key=nil, @summary="CocoaPods plugin which shows info about available CocoaPods plugins.", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.0.0">, @authors=["David Grandinetti", "Olivier Halligon"], @bindir="bin", @cert_chain=[], @dependencies=[<Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="nap" requirements=">= 0">, <Gem::Dependency type=:development name="bundler" requirements="~> 1.3">, <Gem::Dependency type=:development name="rake" requirements=">= 0">], @executables=[], @extensions=[], @extra_rdoc_files=[], @files=[], @licenses=["MIT"], @metadata={}, @platform="ruby", @rdoc_options=[], @require_paths=["lib"], @required_ruby_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f96381d7b28 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "2.0.0">]]>, @required_rubygems_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f96381d7ee8 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "0">]]>, @requirements=[], @rubygems_version="3.3.2", @specification_version=4, @test_files=[], @new_platform="ruby", @full_name="cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0", @full_require_paths=["/Users/kevin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib"] cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0>, @base_dir="/Users/kevin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @gems_dir="/Users/kevin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @default_gem=false, @activated=true> Did you mean?  activated? /Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:93:in` safe_activate_and_require'
/Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins' /Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in` map'
/Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins' /Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in` block in run'
/Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each' /Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in` run'
/Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/bin/pod:25:in `load' /Users/xyz/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/bin/pod:25:in` '

I do not need a fix. I just want to know versions of Ruby and Cocoapods that are compatible and allow me to make progress on developing my Flutter app on Macos.

Answer (score 0):

After I posted the above issue, others encountered the same problem as reported here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11134

The workaround for the problem is to use Ruby 2.7.5. After installing that version, I found Cocoapods 1.11.2 is compatible with Ruby 2.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

brew install ruby@2.7

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Thanks. As noted in the issue report at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11134, the problem was caused by claide gem. The fix has been available since Jan. 12, 2022.